# What does the .api mean in face_recognition.api.face_locations? - face_recognition package python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a difference between `face_recognition.api.face_locations` and `face_recognition.face_locations`. The [offical documentation](https://face-recognition.readthedocs.io/en/latest/face_recognition.html) explains the use of the former while many example codes use the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are willing to use your face recognition program from a api provider like Microsoft, im not really sure(even tho i used the library quite a lot). In another way if you are planning to do the coding and processing on your computer, .api funtion is kind of useless(you wont need it).

Now if you need more inf check out this example that should help you understant the diffrence between the 2 : https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/tree/master/face_recognition

Hope This helped you :)

Feel free to ask any question

Comment: I understand now. Thank you!!